# HX711 gaps in data

Tags: raspberry-pi-pico, hx711

I am using an HX711 connected to a Raspberry Pi Pico to read some load cells and send the data up to a Raspberry Pi via USB, using a Python library for the HX711.

I am chasing an intermittent problem where the updates via USB seem to stop briefly every day or two and in some cases seem to stop indefinitely until power is cycled to the Pico/HX711. I am trying to diagnose the issue remotely but have added various logging options in the Pi.

Has anyone seen the updates from an HX711 pause or hang?

I normally see updates about every 85 ms (nominally 10 Hz,) but my logging code has seen lack up updates for longer than 300 ms. This may not be the HX711 but that is one straw I am grasping at.

Comment: @winny thanks for the edit. Apparently I have been incorrectly using mS for millisecond for years!

Comment: You’re welcome! A personal pet peeve.

Comment: Take the hx711 out of the equation. My suspicion is that it might be micropython running out of memory. It might be a 32bit timer rolling over.

Comment: in my experience the HX711 communication seems to be quiet shaky. We worked arount it by detecting a stale and reset it then by pulling PD_SCK high for 0.01s. But I would love to see the real reason why HX711 tend to get stuck.

Comment: I replaced the HX711 with a new module and the problem disappeared... BUT about a month later it reappeared but to a much less frequent degree  ??